# RocksDB IO error: lock db/LOCK: No locks available

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, server, rocksdb

I am developing a multithreaded server that stores and reads information from a db. The db is implemented with RocksDB.

The problem i am having is that when i access the db from more than one thread at a time, i get that error.

Usually, it ment that the db wasn't deleted after usign it, but now it doesn't make sense, of course it isn't deleted, it's being used by another thread.

I know that the db itself is accessed in secuential order, so tecnically you will never get two threads reading it at the same time, but at least one of them should wait until the lock is released and access it then

anyone has any idea what might happen?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that i had 2 rocksdb::DB* objects in different threads with the same db name and was opening the db from both threads at the same time